# Adaptive Linear regression

Tags: matlab, filtering, linear-regression, best-fit-curve

Let's say I have a set of samples, which consists of a non-stationary stochastic process with a uniform probability distribution (Gaussian). I need an adaptive linear regression over the set of samples. Basically I want the 'best-fit' line to behave a certain way. I have a **separate** signal, and I know the 'best-fit' line of the form Y=Mx+B will have a slope M **proportional** to that other signal. So I need the optimization problem to minimize the distance between the points BUT giving me a slope proportional to the other signal. What's the simplest machine learning/stats approach to use for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you can just use normal regression, or a gradient descent type algorithm, but instead of having the degrees of freedom as M and B, you can use a proportionality constant to M of the known data, and a separate B.

ie. the known signal:

```
Y1 = M1*x + B1
Y2 = k*M1*x + B2
```

solve for k and B2 such that the mean difference to x and y is minimised.

In theory, this seems to be intrinsic anyway. If you solved the problem for a linear solution in the first place. k would be  M2 / M1 ....